# How can I use the debugging tool in Repl.it?

Tags: python, debugging

[image]

I see that **Repl.it** [has a debugging functionality](https://blog.repl.it/python-debugger) . But, I could not use it.

Can anyone tell me how to use debugging in Repl.it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response but hopefully it will help others that may have issues with this.

You would need to set the breakpoints where you want to stop the code execution.  You do that by clicking, in the editor, immediately to the left of the line number in the empty space.  A colored circle will appear indicating you've set a breakpoint on the current line.  Then click on the Debug icon in the left menu.  Finally click the Run button that appears on the left and use the other buttons to step through!